# Cordova add Android platform

Tags: android, cordova, platform

I'm trying to create a prgetto Cordova. The problem is when I go to add the Android platform.
After this command:

```
cordova add Android platform
```

I have an answer from the shell this message:

```
Creating Android project ...

    /home/francesco/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                        throw e;
                              ^
    Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "Android" command not in your PATH. You must Fulfill at least one of These conditions.
        at /home/francesco/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:159:19
        at _fulfilled (/home/francesco/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/francesco/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/francesco/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
        at /home/francesco/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
        at flush (/home/francesco/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js: 415: 13)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js: 499: 11)
        at startup (node.js: 119: 16)
        at node.js: 902: 3
    Error: /home/francesco/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.6.4/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
        at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js: 98: 17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js: 743: 16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js: 810: 5)
```

I looked around but I could not solve. Can someone help me? There rinngrazio in advance.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17977487/1775295) about setting the environment variables correctly.

Comment: I can not figure out where to add it. Is putting me in a little trouble.

Comment: Add what? If you don't know how to edit your path, then Google, how to edit path.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong command. Use 

`cordova platform add android`

Comment: So, seems that you have to setup an environment variable called ANDROID_HOME in which you have to insert the path of the Android SDK.

Comment: I can not figure out where to add it. Is putting me in a little trouble.

Comment: Try this command line instructions:
`set ANDROID_HOME=C:\<installation location>\android-sdk-windows`

and then
`set 
PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`

Comment: The problem is that in the SDK version I downloaded, the platform-tools folder does not exist. There are only platroms and tools

Answer (score 1):

Set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to point to your Android SDK installation.

Then run this command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the official [guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html).

1. You need to install the Android SDK
2. You have to add android tools to your PATH environment variable

You can do it by adding (and adapting) this to your /home/francesco/.bashrc:

```
PATH = $PATH:/home/francesco/android-sdk/platform-tools:/home/francesco/android-sdk/tools
```