# android SDK path not working for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu-16.04, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to run a phonegap app on my Ubuntu machine.

I a getting the error related to the path for the `ANDROID_HOME`.

This is what I have in my `bash_profile`

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/suraj/Android/Sdk
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/home/suraj/Android/Sdk/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/home/suraj/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

After putting this I am doing `source ~/.bashrc` to restart.

What is wrong here?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/33729313/5026476

Comment: Could you print the output of "echo $PATH" please ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu..

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/ct9X7cJY) you go @Ika

Comment: Why do you need to put `$ANDROID_HOME/home/suraj/Android/Sdk/`? The variable **already contains** your home directory path. Also, your image shows `.rvm/bin` duplicated a few times in your path, so I'd suggest cleaning that up

Comment: How do I exactly do that cleaning?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any reference to the Android SDK in the output of "echo $PATH".
Make sure your PATH variable contains the Android SDK.

Try to add the following lines to you .bashrc and then source it.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/suraj/Android/Sdk
PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}
PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

Comment: Yes but it seems that the PATH variable is not updated.

Comment: The path does have it... At the end `/tools:/platform-tools`

Comment: This doesn't help @Ika

Answer (score 0):

Path's are not set properly in your bashrc:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/suraj/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/home/suraj/Android/Sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/suraj/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/suraj/Android/Sdk/Sdk/build-tools

source ~/.bashrc

echo $PATH
```